# Run tests on xcode 7.3 : could not build Objective-C module 'libxml2'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I create a simple test class on swift 2.0 with xcode 7.3:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyTestProject

class ChangeWishListTests: XCTestCase {

    func testViewLoad() {
        let changeWishListVC = ChangeWishListViewController()
        changeWishListVC.viewDidLoad()

        XCTAssert(changeWishListVC.view != nil, "Passed")
    }        
}
```

And use this library for xml parsing: https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

But when i run tests, i get error:

> :0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'libxml2'

Comment: is the libxml2 library linked with test target ?

Comment: where do i can check this ?

Comment: Have you added the path to `header search paths`?

Comment: i installed libraries with CocoaPods

Comment: i have `$(inherited)` value there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i missed to add in pods file libraries:

```
target 'MyProjectTests' do
pod 'Kanna', '~> 1.0.0'
end
```